# Preventing Request Spamming

Tags: performance, http, dictionary, geospatial, webrequest

**Scenario**

A client application that features a map. The map is an interactive control that upon move/zoom will request tiles (as needed) from a tile server -- a [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Welcome) in this case. The tile server receives requests for tiles as the user moves around the interactive map. **Let us imagine that there is no limit on how many requests the client can make.**

**Problem**

When a user is moving fast, requests to the tile server pile up. The tile server gets bogged down and is not able to provide tiles in a timely fashion.

Additionally, the tile request queue is responded to in request order. So, the user could go from Florida to California and have to wait for Florida tiles to load before seeing any tiles in California.

---

**Questions**

How can we improve the perceived performance of the client?

What are some strategies to employ on the client-side to prevent a large amount of requests when panning fast? Zooming fast?

What are some strategies to employ on the server-side to determine if a request is no longer needed or should take lower priority?

---

**Possible Solution**

Place a custom proxy in front of the Tile Server such that tiles could be requested with a time-stamp -- later tiles always receiving priority. The proxy could also implement a feature allowing the client application to abandon a request.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I looked at various solutions on stopping image loading. But it seems no one has found a way to stop loading an image when browser has already started downloading it.

So, I can recommend alternative. Browser has a limit of 2 parallel downloads per domain. So, that means you need to load images of different locations from different subdomain so that browser can load multiple locations in parallel.

So, say california images are coming from:

california.yourwebsite.com/images

And florida images from:

florida.yourwebsite.com/images

Moreover, you can use different subdomain for different zoom level so that if images for a certain zoom level are still loading and user chages zoom level, browser can download the new zoom level images immediately.

zoom10.florida.yourwebsite.com/images

For this, you need to create a *.yourwebsite.com DNS mapping to your webserver(s) from your domain panel.

Does this answer your question?

Comment: The problem is not the limit of browser requests (because the client is not running in a browser.) Thanks for looking up the "stop image loading." That was a big question for me: Is it possible to cancel a request? There's only one way I can think of that working, and that's with a proxy that waits until the request is responded to or it receives a cancel.

Comment: If you have a desktop application, then the solution is easy, just beef up the system.net maxConcurrentConnection limit per IP. By default a desktop app can only make 2 concurrent requests to an IP. You can increase that in app.Config. See this: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/quickwins.aspx)

Comment: The problem is not that the machine can't make the requests. The problem is that when the request is made, it adds more load to the tile server. This means that tiles that are requested, but not needed still need to be processed by the tile server.

Comment: Agree, but I assume the tiles are static images, not dynamic images generated on the fly. In that case, the load is minimal. My gut says approx 30% image load will be waste, not more than that. So, 30% additional static image delivery should not cause visible problem to your webserver.

Comment: You mentioned you have desktop application. In that case you should have full control over image load. How are you loading the images?